# ZedGraph, multiple solid colors for chart background based on X or Z value

Tags: c#, .net, zedgraph

I need the chart background of a bar chart to depend on the X-value, in order to display for example 2 solid colors, like green for data points for current day, and white on earlier data points. I could set the Z-value as a 0/1 "trigger". But I can't see how the background color can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the background color of the zedGraphControl?

```
private GraphPane _myPane;

_myPane = zedGraphControl.GraphPane;
_myPane.Chart.Fill.Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
```

Comment: No. Multiple solid colors on the same chart. Like a gradient, just not gradient, but solid colors based on data z-value.